# Determine the source of the image used in google earth

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Programatically, is there any way to determine the source of the images used in the google earth map that is currently visible in the viewport? By source I mean where they get the images. I know that not all images used are coming from google. Some are coming from US Navy, CNES, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It tells you on the screen.......

Look at the bottom in the middle. It generally says something like
Image 'copyright symbol' 2012 Company Name
sometimes there are multiple credits given

Edit: Just noticed the first word - 'programatically' - No I don't know how to do that.

Maybe you could take a screenshot and use some kind of OCR software to read the words??
It is probably impossible for a number of reasons, especially since a lot of the time it is using images from a number of different sources depending on your zoom level.